# VBA: How to return a cell reference from a variable that looksup a value?

Tags: excel, vba, match

First of all, I have very little experience with VBA. Here is my problem:

I need to update a certain rate on a daily base in order to perform investments calculations. Right now, I  have a button that once clicked brings the day's rate automatically from a website, and I have to copy and paste the rate to its respective date manually. What I would like to do it to just click the button and the rate would automatically be pasted next to its date. The worksheet looks like this:

```
                                                Update Button
                                           Day's date        Day's rate
                                           03/01/2013            6%

  Date           Rate        
02/01/2013        5%
03/01/2013        6%
04/01/2013
```

The most obvious way to do it would be to use vlookup to look for the the day's date up right and paste it in the correct place at column B, but the problem would be that everytime I update the value, the previous day formula would result in an error. So the best solution would be to use a simple macro that matches the day's date in column A and pastes only the value of the rate next to it. 
A good strategy to perform this action with normal worksheet functions would be `=CELL("address";INDEX(B:B;MATCH($G$5;A:A;0);))`, which would result in the cell reference of the right day's rate in column B. The problem is there isn't the =CELL function in VBA.

I tried the following script but it didn't work out:

```
Sub Teste2()

Dim IndexFormula As Range

MatchFormula = WorksheetFunction.Match(Range("Today"), Range("A:A"), 0)
IndexFormula = WorksheetFunction.Index(Range("B:B"), MatchFormula, 0)

Value = IndexFormula.Address

Range("G5").Select
Selection.Copy
Value.Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False

End Sub
```

What code should I use?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use [Find](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839746(v=office.15).aspx) function:

```
Sub Teste2()
    Dim res As Range        
    Set res = Range("A:A").Find(What:=Range("Today"), Lookat:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False)        
    If Not res Is Nothing Then
        ' res.Offset(, 1) will give you column B (1 to the right from A)
        res.Offset(, 1).Value = Range("G5").Value
    End If
End Sub
```

**Some notes:**

- don't use variables with specific names such `Value`. One time you'd be confused with unexpected results
- instead using `Copy/PasteSpecial xlPasteValues` you could use just `Range("A1").Value = Range("B1").Value`
- [**avoid using Select/Active statements**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/excel-macro-avoiding-using-select/10718179#10718179) in your code

Comment: Original method was much faster, almost 10 times faster.

Comment: in my PC with 100K rows in column A Find gives me `0.103125`, Index/Match - `0.045625`. It's not a big differents. [Screen](https://www.dropbox.com/s/3p6d6e9p2eot7ky/test.png)

Comment: ~2.5 X faster isn't a big difference? That's huge to anyone I've ever worked for. But, my comment wasn't as much to say your wrong as much as I was wondering what benefit your approach had, when rewritten the original is shorter and faster, so I was wondering why you felt it wasn't sufficient, especial when if you do only a match and exclude the Index it is even faster and cleaner.

Comment: I tested with 100K rows, and I think OP has less rows. If for 100K rows it evaluates for 1/10 sec, I don't think that OP would fill any difference

Answer (score 1):

You are very close with your try just make a few small changes as below and it will work, No need to use a find as it will be slower:

```
Dim MatchFormula As Long
Dim IndexFormula As Range

MatchFormula = WorksheetFunction.Match(Range("Today"), Range("A:A"), 0)
Set IndexFormula = WorksheetFunction.Index(Range("B:B"), MatchFormula, 0)

IndexFormula.Value = Range("G5").Value
```

More so if you want it to be even faster you can use:

```
Dim MatchFormula As Long

MatchFormula = WorksheetFunction.Match(Range("Today"), Range("A:A"), 0)
Range("B" & MatchFormula).Value = Range("G5").Value
```

This works because the Match on the Column returns the row with your value and you can just reference that row in column B to void the need of using index.